# how to save folder in /usr/local with swift with permission

Tags: macos

I want to create a folder by swift program. My code is something like that:

```
  let fileManager = FileManager()
  let dataPath = "/usr/local/newfolder"
  do{
     try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath:dataPath,        withIntermediateDirectories:false, attributes:nil)
  } catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
```

But I got the following error message

> You don’t have permission to save the file “newFolder” in the folder
>   “local”.

I want to use root permission like using sudo command. How can I do that?

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "sudo"
task.arguments = ["install", "-v", "-m0755", "-d", "/usr/local/new_directory"]
task.launch()
```

Comment: I hope you are doing well, I also need to create the folder in the same directory from swift program /usr/local/testable  I used your solution, NSTask got updated with the Process(). I am facing this error 'launch path not accessible'